# The normalizer of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf Z)$ in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf Q)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

It seems that the normalizer of $H=\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf Z)$ in $G=\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf Q)$ is "almost" equal to itself, that is, 
$$
N_G(\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf Z))=Z(G) \cdot \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf Z)
$$ 
where $Z(G)$ is the centre of $G.$  Is there a simple proof/disproof of this fact? More generally, for which integral domains $R$ it is known that $\mathrm{GL}(n,R)$ "almost" coincides with its normalizer in the group $\mathrm{GL}(n,Q(R))$ where $Q(R)$ is the quotient field of $R?$

Comment: You need to add the scalar matrices, at least.

Comment: @Plop: I will, thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you should try asking this on MathOverflow.

Comment: Right. $\phantom{abc}$

Comment: The interested readers may find Emerton's answer to the question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/80667/the-normalizer-of-mathrmgln-mathbf-z-in-mathrmgln-mathbf-q

Comment: @Emerton Maybe you want to copy your answer on mathoverflow here, so that this question gets removed from the unanswered tab.

Comment: @Julian. Emerton = Matt E here, I think? Anyway, you can't ping him, as he hasn't participated in this thread.

Answer (score 2):

For an integral domain $R$ with quotient field $k$, $GL_n(R)$ is the stabilizer in $GL_n(k)$ of the $R$-module $R^n$ in $k^n$. Anything normalizing $GL_n(R)$ sends $R^n$ to another subset of $k^n$ stabilized by $GL_n(R)$. For a PID $R$, a given $0\not=v\in k^n$ can have its "denominator" collected-up so as to write $v=t\cdot v'$ with $v'$ primitive, $t\in k^\times$. Then $GL_n(R)\cdot v = t\cdot GL_n(R)\cdot w=t\cdot R^n$. That is, for a PID, the non-zero $GL_n(R)$ orbits are scalar multiples of $R^n$. Thus, anything $h$ in the normalizer of $GL_n(R)$ maps $R^n$ to $t\cdot R^n$ for some $t\in k^\times$, so, up to $GL_n(R)$, is a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

This is true for $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ inside $GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ for every prime. Use $\prod\limits_p GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p) \subset \prod\limits_p GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ and intersect with the diagonally embedded $GL_n(\mathbb{Q})$. This gives you the proof.